# How to enable error_reporting only for administrator?

Tags: administrator, error-handling, error-reporting

There are many times that I need to debug issues on the administration area of Joomla and need to do so on the live site. But I don't want to enable error_reporting also for the front-end.
Is there anyway to enable error_reporting only for the admin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My most convenient trick I use in this case, is by creating a temporary hack on the framework.php file, inside the

> /administrator/includes/ directory.

The error reporting for the admin is handled in framework.php ~line 52.

```
// Set the error_reporting
switch ($config->error_reporting)
{
    case 'default':
    case '-1':
        break;

    case 'none':
    case '0':
        error_reporting(0);

        break;
```

Make the following changes:

```
// Set the error_reporting
switch ($config->error_reporting)
{
    case 'default':
    case '-1':
        break;

    case 'none':
    case '0':
        error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        //error_reporting(0);

        break;
```

After debug is done, I revert back these changes.

Comment: I have to admit, this is a feature that should be integrated into the Global Configuration.

Comment: So will this show error reporting for each admin user on can it be user-specific?

Comment: @johnny_s,  
It will display errors for all in the backend. I don't think you can make such distinction at this point to enable error_reporting only for super user, but I might be wrong. - Joomla Agency, posted an answer with a link to a plugin for this.

Comment: @Lodder if you believe this, would you support a pull request if I made it?

Comment: @Eoin, thinking about it now, no. It should really be done at development level before a site goes live. Then again, that's my personal opinion. Others may feel differently

Comment: I agree. That plugin is free anyway and is great

Comment: Even so, I can't think of many reasons for error reporting to show to the public

Comment: @Lodder I found a really good reason to avoid this.  If access privileges have not been activated yet you won't see a PHP error.  Found out by using that plugin and the error came before the plugin was called.  So yes, it should stay as is.

Answer (score 6):

Try this small Plugin from Viktor Vogel. This plugin gives the possibility to control the reporting per user group. Big advantage of this is, that you don't need to hack core files.

http://joomla-extensions.kubik-rubik.de/eer-easy-error-reporting

Comment: This is great, but you should make sure it is the first plugin called or it will not catch errors.  If you still don't see errors but get something obvious like a white screen then you should turn on global configuration to see the error.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an .htaccess file into administrator directory with:

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting <integer>
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127980/enabling-error-display-in-php-via-htaccess-only